# Java. Singleton and getInstance with parameters

Tags: java, singleton

I have a code like this:

```
public class Hero extends Costam {

    private static Hero heroInstance;

    Weapon weapon;
    static Image idleImg = new ImageIcon("idle.png").getImage();
    static Image movingImg = new ImageIcon("moving.png").getImage();
    static Image fallingImg = new ImageIcon("falling.png").getImage();
    static Image jumpingImg = new ImageIcon("jumping.png").getImage();

    private LinkedList<Sprite> sprajty;
    private ArrayList<Segment> plansza;

    static int[] idleArray = new int[]{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, movingArray = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            fallingArray = new int[]{0}, jumpingArray = new int[]{0, 1, 2};

    static ArrayList<Image> obrazy = new ArrayList<Image>() {
        {
            add(idleImg);
            add(movingImg);
            add(fallingImg);
            add(jumpingImg);

        }
    };

    static ArrayList<int[]> tablice = new ArrayList<int[]>() {
        {
            add(idleArray);
            add(movingArray);
            add(fallingArray);
            add(jumpingArray);

        }
    };

    private Hero(ArrayList<Segment> plansza, LinkedList<Sprite> sprajty) {
        super(new Sprite(plansza, obrazy, tablice));
        this.plansza = plansza;
        weapon = new BasicWeapon(new ImageIcon("blue-portal.png").getImage());
        this.sprajty = sprajty;

        velocityX = 8;
    }

    //SINGLETON - ten get instance btw
    public Hero getInstance ()
    {
        if (heroInstance == null)
        {
            heroInstance = new Hero(plansza, sprajty);
        }
        return heroInstance;
    }

    public static Hero getInstance (ArrayList<Segment> plansza, LinkedList<Sprite> sprajty)
    {
        if (heroInstance == null) {
            heroInstance = new Hero(plansza,sprajty);
        }
        return heroInstance;
    }
```

As you can see, there is a getInstance method with parametres, which is not acceptable in Singleton. How to resolve it? Thank you.
I tried to replace it by init method, but have no idea how to continue it.

Comment: This doesn't look like it should be a singleton, or any special kind of class at all.

Comment: _Why_ should the `Hero` class be a singleton -- what is the reason for this design?

Answer (score 1):

Right. It's not a `Singleton`. It is a [`Multiton`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) which **expands on the singleton concept to manage a map of named instances as key-value pairs**.

Comment: So, the code is proper and I should consider it as Mutliton? ;)